# How can i do elemMatch inside array using mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have below user details in my **bookings** collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609a382b589346973c84c6fe"),
    "Name" : "abc",
    "UserId":1
    "Status" : "Pending",    
    "BookingData" : {
        "Date" : ISODate("2021-04-30T04:00:00.000Z"),
        "info" : [],
        "BookingDataMethod" : "avf",
        "Message" : null,
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60a4e92775e5de3570578820"),
                "ProductName" : "Test1",
                "ProductID" : ObjectId("60a4e92475e5de357057880a"),
                "IsDeliveryFailed" : "Yes"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60a4e92775e5de357057881f"),
                "ProductName" : "Test2",
                "ProductID" : ObjectId("60a4e92475e5de357057880d")
            }
        ],
        
    }
    
}
```

I have prepared a query for the below conditions and when I run the below query I should get the **"UserId":1** documents but I got **0** records

**condition 1**: products should not be null

**condition 2**: ProductID should exist in the products array and should not be null
**condition 3**: IsDeliveryFailed should not be "Yes"

Based on the above user only one product got delivery failed(IsDeliveryFailed": "Yes") so when I run this query it should return "UserId":1 document. if both products **"IsDeliveryFailed": "Yes"** then
we should not get this user

**Query**

```
db.getCollection('bookings').find({
    "$and": [
              { "BookingData.products": { $ne: [] } },
              { "BookingData.products": {"$elemMatch":{ "ProductID": { "$exists": true ,$ne: null } }} },
              { "BookingData.products": {"$elemMatch":{ "IsDeliveryFailed": { $ne: 'Yes' } }} }
            ]
})
```

Could someone please tell me the issue on the above query or please help me to prepare a query for the above condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with aggregations

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "BookingData.products": { "$exists": true }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "BookingData.products": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$BookingData.products",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              { $ne: [ "$$this.ProductID", undefined ] },
              { $ne: [ "$$this._id", null ] },
              { $ne: [ "$$this.IsDeliveryFailed", "Yes" ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [ "$BookingData.products", [] ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hVunqHAqHsd)**

Comment: if both product "IsDeliveryFailed": "Yes" then we should not show this user please check https://mongoplayground.net/p/bPhSY1cHvmi .now its showing user with empty products but my expectation it should not return this user.

Comment: So if the products is an empty array, we will not show right? Is that the final conclusion out of these condition?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please have a look

Comment: what does { $ne: [ "$$this._id", null ] } mean ? could you please help me to understand

Comment: Sure. we can filter an array using `$filter`. `$ne` means `not equal to` which validates your second condition, always productId should be there which cannot be null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232632/discussion-between-its-me-and-varman).

Comment: Thanks for the query but I did the same this and it's not working please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618691/how-can-i-do-mongodb-aggrigate-filter-for-multiple-collection