# How can i do Mongodb aggrigate filter for multiple collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collection bookings and invoices and I have prepared aggregate and lookup query for below condition

bookings collection condition

**condition 1: Status not equal to delivered**

**condition 2: products should not be null or empty**

**condition 3: ProductID should exist in the products array and should not be null**

**condition 4: IsDeliveryFailed should not be "Yes"**

***bookings Collection Data***

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609a382b589346973c84c6fe"),
    "Name" : "abc",
    "UserId":1
    "Status" : "Pending", 
    "Invoices" : [ 
        ObjectId("709a382b5c6fe89346973c84")
    ],  
    "BookingData" : {
        "Date" : ISODate("2021-04-30T04:00:00.000Z"),
        "info" : [],
        "BookingDataMethod" : "avf",
        "Message" : null,
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60a4e92775e5de3570578820"),
                "ProductName" : "Test1",
                "ProductID" : ObjectId("60a4e92475e5de357057880a"),
                "IsDeliveryFailed" : "Yes"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60a4e92775e5de357057881f"),
                "ProductName" : "Test2",
                "ProductID" : ObjectId("60a4e92475e5de357057880d")
            }
        ],
        
    }
    
}
```

invoices collection condition

**condition 1: InvoiceData should not be null or empty**

**condition 2: InvoiceID should exist in the InvoiceData array and should not be null**

**condition 3: IsPaymentFailed should not be "Yes"**

***invoices Collection Data***

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("709a382b5c6fe89346973c84"),    
    "invoiceNumber":1
    "InvoiceData" :[
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60a4e92775e5de3570578820"),
                "ProductName" : "Test1",
                "InvoiceID":1,
                "IsPaymentFailed" : "Yes"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60a4e92775e5de357057881f"),
                "InvoiceID":2,
                "ProductName" : "Test2",
                
            }
    
    ]
    
}
```

**Query**

```
db.bookings.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "Status": {
        $ne: "Delivered"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "invoices",
      "localField": "Invoices",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "invoiceInfo"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "BookingData.products": {
            "$exists": true
          }
        },
        {
          "invoiceInfo.InvoiceData": {
            "$exists": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
 {
    $set: {
      "BookingData.products": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$BookingData.products",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              { $ne: [ "$$this.ProductID", undefined ] },
              { $ne: [ "$$this._id", null ] },
              { $ne: [ "$$this.IsDeliveryFailed", "Yes" ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
 {
    $set: {
      "invoiceInfo.InvoiceData": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$invoiceInfo.InvoiceData",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              { $ne: [ "$$this.InvoiceID", undefined ] },
              { $ne: [ "$$this._id", null ] },
              { $ne: [ "$$this.IsPaymentFailed", "Yes" ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $ne: [
              "$BookingData.products",
              [],
              
            ]
          },
          {
            $ne: [
              "$invoiceInfo.InvoiceData",
              [],
              
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  
])
```

this is not working as expected for example if

The query should return the above document

if ProductID exist and products exist and all products do not have IsDeliveryFailed: "Yes"

if ProductID exist and products exist and anyone products do not have IsDeliveryFailed: "Yes"

if InvoiceID exist and InvoiceData exist and all InvoiceData do not have IsPaymentFailed: "Yes"

if InvoiceID exist and InvoiceData exist and anyone InvoiceData does not has IsPaymentFailed: "Yes"

another set

if ProductID exists and products exist and all products are IsDeliveryFailed: "Yes" flag. but we have to check invoices collection
if InvoiceID exist and InvoiceData exist and anyone InvoiceData does not have IsPaymentFailed: "Yes" then we have to return this document

if InvoiceID exist and InvoiceData exist and all InvoiceData are IsPaymentFailed: "Yes".but we have to check bookings collection
if ProductID exist and products exist and anyone products does not have IsDeliveryFailed:"Yes" then we have to returndocument

[**Mongo playground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Iy7oHobu_F)

Comment: is ur `invoiceInfo` an array? or always having one element?

Comment: invoiceInfo  will be an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have explained your previous problem in [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67603426/7975771). Since the invoiceInfo is an array and `invoiceData` also an array inside `invoiceInfo`, we use map and filter. Then we need to exclude empty array of `invoiceData`. (This can be done in previous step also like filter-map->filter, but it could be lengthy, thats why I used it in next stage )

Here is the code

```
db.bookings.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "PaymentStatus": { $ne: "Delivered" }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "BookingData.products": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$BookingData.products",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              { $ne: [ "$$this.ProductID", undefined ] },
              { $ne: [ "$$this._id", null ] },
              { $ne: [ "$$this.IsDeliveryFailed", "Yes" ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "invoices",
      "localField": "Invoices",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "invoiceInfo"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      invoiceInfo: {
        $map: {
          input: "$invoiceInfo",
          as: "info",
          in: {
            InvoiceData: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$$info.InvoiceData",
                as: "data",
                "cond": {
                  $and: [
                    { $ne: [ "$$data.InvoiceID", undefined ] },
                    { $ne: [ "$$data.InvoiceID", null ] },
                    { $ne: [ "$$data.IsPaymentFailed", "Yes" ] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      invoiceInfo: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$invoiceInfo",
          cond: { $ne: [ "$$this.InvoiceData", [] ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          { $ne: [ "$BookingData.products", [] ] },
          { $ne: [ "$invoiceInfo", [] ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cFVMsfqeCWV)**

Hope this will help you. This is the time you need to play/ workaround based on your requirement. Sometimes you need to do lookup before or after the current location in demo